# Perl: string length limitations in real life

Tags: string, perl, limit

While, for example, [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) documents that scalar strings in Perl are limited only by available memory, I'm strongly suspecting in real life there would be some other limits.

I'm considering the following ideas:

- I'm not sure how strings are implemented in Perl — is there some sort of byte/character counter? If there is, then probably it's implemented as a platform-dependent integer (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit), so effectively it would limit strings to something like `2 ** 31`, `2 ** 32`, `2 ** 63` or `2 ** 64` bytes.
- If Perl doesn't use a counter and instead uses some byte to terminate the string (which would be strange, as it's perfectly ok to have a string like "foo\0bar" in Perl), then all operations would inevitably get much slower as string length increases.
- Most string functions that Perl deals with strings, such as [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html), for example, return normal scalar integer, and I strongly suspect that it would be platform-limited integer too.

So, what would be the other factors that limit Perl string length in real life? What should be considered an okay string length for practical purposes?

Comment: `perl -E '$x = "x" x (2 ** 31); $y = $x x 7;say length $y'` returns `15032385536` for me, but `$x x 8` segfaults. I have 16 GB, `ptrsize=8`.

Comment: Regarding the first point: How many 64-bit machines have more than 2^64 bytes of memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It keep track of the size of the buffer and the number of bytes therein.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$x="abcdefghij"; Dump($x);'
SV = PV(0x9222b00) at 0x9222678
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x9238220 "abcdefghij"\0
  CUR = 10                        <-- 10 bytes used
  LEN = 12                        <-- 12 bytes allocated
```

- On a 32-bit build of Perl, it uses 32-bit unsigned integer for these values. This is (exactly) large enough to create a string that uses up your process's entire 4 GiB address space.
- On a 64-bit build of Perl, it uses 64-bit unsigned integer for those values. This is (exactly) large enough to create a string that uses up your process's entire 16 [EiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exbibit) address space.

The docs are correct. The size of the string is limited only by available memory.

Comment: Technically, I can use set up Perl (with build-time options) to use 32-bit integers on a 64-bit platform. Thus, while running on 64-bit platform (with >4 GiB of memory available and huge address space), I'll still be limited to 4 GiB?

Comment: Please note the lack of word platform anywhere in my answer. It doesn't matter if you have a 64-bit platform if you run your program in a 32-bit environment. If you run a 32-bit build on a 64-bit platform, the 32-bit integer is still large enough to address all of the process's 4GB of address space. The size of the string is limited only by available memory: 4GB, minus what's reserved by the OS, minus what's already used up.

Comment: I'm not talking about 32-bit build (i.e. when `file` reports `ELF 32-bit LSB executable`), I'm talking about 64-bit build, but with built-time params such as `longsize` or `ptrsize` (I'm not sure whatever `CUR` and `LEN` inside a scalar use) set to 4 instead of 8. Technically, this binary has much more than 4 GiB available, but I strongly suspect it would be able address only 4 GiBs of strings.

Comment: That can't happen. A 64-bit build has 64-bit pointers (ptrsize=8) by definition, and Perl integers are guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer (ivsize>=ptrsize). Like I already said, a 64-bit build uses 64-bit integers for CUR and LEN.

Comment: It could in theory use larger numbers for CUR and LEN, but not smaller.