# Is there any limit for scalar variable in perl?

Tags: perl, mmap

Now I'm working with large file, which size is greater than (1.5 GB). So I used `File::Map`. When the input is greater than `2.1 GB` script failed with showing error `Use of uninitialized value $count in print at file.pl line 16.`.

**But script is running `2.1GB and below 2.1GB`**

My script is as below

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Map 'map_file';
my $filename ="/root/Desktop/test_sequence/human_genome";

map_file (my $map,$filename);

my $count;

$count++ while ($map=~/>/g);

print $count; #The file has only 14 `>` so result is 14.
```

At the same time I tried it without the module. It is also terminate with same error.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $filename ="/root/Desktop/test_sequence/human_genome";

open my $fh,"<",$filename or die "$!";

my $m = do{local $/; <$fh>};

my $count;

$count++ while ($m=~/>/g);

print $count;
```

I don't know what is the problem here?

Comment: If all you're doing is counting the `>` - do you actually need to read the whole file into memory at all?

Comment: @Sobrique I'm trying to find the repeats in a file. So I want to count the headers in a file. Then I'll proceed.

Comment: Point is - you might _still_ find a 'two-pass' approach (read the file looking for the markers, read the file again to process it) is altogether more efficient, unless you need to do a lot of data set cross referencing.

Comment: @Sobrique Ohh yes thank you. Now my doubt is, this kind of situation (processing the big file) File::Map is use full or not?

Comment: Depends an AWFUL LOT on what you're doing with the data - there is no need to hold it in memory, unless you're needing to access the whole thing.

Comment: `mmap`ping the file is usually a great technique because it holds just as much of the file in memory as the system can afford. I just tried (see my amended answer) with a 5 GB file of zeroes that had three `>` characters sprinkled into it, and it takes less than 6s to count them. Could you try just writing `$map` to another file after the `map_file()` call and see how much you get at different sizes of the input file?

Comment: @mbethke: *"Could you try just writing `$map`"* Do you mean `mmap`? And I think the OP has already tried what you call `mmap`. What is your suggestion to use `mmap` from within Perl?

Comment: @Borodin no, I meant the contents of the `$map` scalar that should reflect the contents of `human_genome`. `mmap()` is just what `File::Map` uses internally. Apparently he doesn't get a single match once the file gets bigger than what I suppose are 2^31 bytes, so I'd be curious what Perl sees in the variable in that case. May be that it gets cut off at 2G, or some overflow resets it to zero-length, or it gets corrupted, ...

Comment: Are you sure you don't get `Use of uninitialized value $map in pattern match (m//)` or `Use of uninitialized value $m in pattern match (m//)` beforehand?

Comment: There is no `$map` scalar in what you've shown. You're doing a very poor job of presenting your problem so I'm voting to close it.

Comment: What platform are you working on? As far as I can tell `File::Map` works fine on Windows, Linux, and OSX.

Comment: @Borodin, you might want to read the OP's code. And no, it's not my problem, the OP's code works fine here. I'm trying to find out what else might be broken in his setup.

Comment: @mbethke: You aren't working with an unmoderated forum here. *"what else might be broken in his setup"* is not the subject of the question. You might want to enjoy [the Stack Overflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and assess your own input.

Comment: @Borodin, the subject is "I don't know what is the problem here?". So tell me, what direction of investigation is permissible here? It's not the OP's code nor `File::Map`. I have verified it. It works as expected here. Have you?

Comment: @mbethke: I'm sorry, I'm talking about a very different question. If I google for that subject line then I get a list of many other questions, but not this one. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hit a signed 32-bit integer limit in one of several places

A 32-bit signed value allows for values from `0x1000_0000` to `0x7FFF_FFFF`, which is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Hence your 2.1GB limit

I don't know whether that is a limit of your build of perl, or if it is part of [`File::Map`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Map)

Files of any size can be handled very simply by reading one line at a time, and since your purpose here seems to be just to count the number of Unicode `GREATER-THAN SIGN` characters, you could do it easily like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant HUMAN_GENOME => '/root/Desktop/test_sequence/human_genome';

my $count = do {

    open my $fh, '<', HUMAN_GENOME or die sprintf qq{Unable to open "%s": $!}, HUMAN_GENOME;

    my $n = 0;

    $n += tr/>// while <$fh>;

    $n;
};

print $count;
```

Comment: That's what I thought but from his perl version that sounds unlikely. And `File::Map` can definitely handle >4 GB so it's really a bit mysterious. Of course a slow working version is better than a fast broken one but grepping through 5 GB in 5.6s thanks to `File::Map` is sexy enough to keep trying a bit ;)

Comment: Okay I'll bite *"that sounds unlikely"*. Why? And what is it about the Perl code that swayed your judgement?

Comment: *"And `File::Map` can definitely handle >4 GB"* If you have evidence of that then please show your code so that it can be verified.

Comment: OP: "I'm working with 64 bit centOS 7". I don't have a CentOS 7 to checkbut I don't think  (hence "unlikely") they would include a 32bit perl on x86_64. My evidence that `File::Map` can handle >4GB is that the OP's first script correctly counted the `>` characters in a 5 GB file on my machine, with the last one beyond 4 GB threshold. I didn't use any other code than what I showed already, and the OP's of course.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed the maximum scalar size. Theoretically it can go up to 4 GB on a 32bit perl but as your address space is limited to accommodate things like the OS, 2-3.5 GB is usually the real limit. Using a 64-bit OS and perl it should work though.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22819092/5403907) for some details.

Edit: works fine here, perl 5.22.2 on Fedora, x86_64-linux-thread-multi:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=zero bs=1M count=5000
5000+0 records in
5000+0 records out
5242880000 bytes (5.2 GB) copied, 34.8694 s, 150 MB/s
$ perl -e 'sub wat{open my $fh, ">>zero" or die $!;
   seek($fh,shift,0); syswrite($fh, ">");}
   wat(1000);
   wat(100_000_000);
   wat(4_500_000_000);'
$ time perl map.pl 
3
real    0m5.638s
user    0m3.921s
sys     0m1.717s
```

Comment: I'm working with 64 bit centOS 7, 32 GB ram. Okay what about  `File::Map`? From my understanding which create the direct link with the file. so why this also can't work?

Comment: What does `perl -v` say?

Comment: @Sobrique It shows `This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 29 registered patches, ..`

Comment: @mkHun: A few lines down it will have a value for `use64bitint`. It's probably `undef`.